# Google Analytics and real-time analytics comparison: Chartbeat vs Clicky vs Mixpanel

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, web-analytics, web-analytics-tools

We're curious to hear opinions about and experiences with Chartbeat, Clicky, Mixpanel, and Google Analytics.

Do people deploy Google and one of these other real-time systems?  Or is the real-time system sufficient to displace Google?

Of the real-time systems, which do you use and why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really have an opinion about Charbeat, Clicky or Mixpanel specifically, but I have lots of experience in other web analytics toos, such as Web Trends, Yahoo Web Analytics, Omniture Site Catalyst, and Google Analytics...

In my experience, real-time reporting is mostly useful for implementation and ongoing QA of the tracking code.  It really depends on the nature of your site but I have yet to see any client that needed real-time reporting. 24 hour delay is more than acceptable, as most clients I have worked with report or expect reports on a weekly, monthly, quarterly, etc.. basis.

IOW it's more useful for your coders but rarely useful for your reporters.  If your website and implementation is solid and not likely to change a whole lot, there is very little value in real-time reporting.

Answer (score 4):

I've tried Google Analytics, ChartBeat and Clicky.

I see **Google Analytics** as a must-have solution for every website. It's rock-solid and has proven itself over several years. Only thing you'll miss here are the real-time updates. That's where ChartBeat and Clicky come into sight.

**ChartBeat** is a great real-time monitor. Other then GA and Clicky this is a paid service. In my experience ChartBeat is more for tech-savy people that want to monitor the current load on the server. It does offers a cool replay option.

**Clicky** offerts the real-time updates that GA lacks. It has a cool Spy feature, where you can monitor which pages are requested by which user. It also logs click activity, like external links, downloads and videos.

*I would suggest you use a combination of tools on your website(s). My favorite combination currently is GA with Clicky.*

P.S. I've recently reviewed these tools on my blog: http://www.fieg.nl/5-analytics-tools-other-then-google-analytics

Comment: Google Analytics has realtime features since this answer was written.